# Windows Container invalid certificate

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

I have an application which I contanerized in Windows Container.

The application is a .NetFramework server that calls another API Service.

I am facing the below exception

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

After researching I created a certificate and added to my Dockerfile

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./certs/ ./certs/

# Filepath refers to the path of cert files inside the container's file system
RUN powershell Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\certs\cert1.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-restore


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["win-container.exe"]
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Is your issue resolved, revert back if you are still facing some issues so that we can assist you further

Answer (score 0):

The error **`System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`** occurs mainly due to following reasons

Self signed Certificates
Invalid Certificates
Broken Certificates

If you are using self signed certificates and they are not getting recognised by you can skip the validation part in your code or add it to trusted certificates.

If you are using invalid certificates (certificates that got expired or taken from intermittent CA) try to generate a new certificate from the trusted or standard CA vendors and also check the hostname for which you have generated the certificate, even though host.example.com and example.com are under same hostname you need to have separate ssl certificates generated for them.

Sometimes while copying or downloading these certificates you might face some issues due to which these certificates will get broken or corrupted as a result it will create a problem while using these certificates. Try various ways for copying these certificates and check the checksum after they got copied to the destination.

Hope this will help you in solving your issues. I’m attaching few links for further reference

[1] https://www.limilabs.com/blog/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure
[2]https://www.positioniseverything.net/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure